# Changing cells formatting based on another cells date

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, date, google-sheets-dates

I've been looking and can't quite find the answer I'm looking for.

I have a spreadsheet with columns Monday through Saturday with data lining up underneath. I would like the current day to highlight so I can read it easier. I can get the date cell to turn but not the rest. You'll see what I mean in the picture. I want all the cells under Wednesday to change color, then for it all to shift when the next day comes. P.S. I'm a newb.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**custom formula applied to whole range:** 

```
=IF(A$1=TODAY(),1)
```

[image: 0]